# How to perform authorization in addition to authentication using SAML

Tags: python, authorization, saml

I already have authentication using SAML using `python3-saml` module
Now I am looking for adding authorization on top of it

The direction I am going for is to utilize the attributes that can be associated with each user as markers for the authorization system

Adding request for the attributes during the login worked - unfortunately it is not enough, since I also need to be able to check the user credentials even if I do NOT have an interactive login with the user

For that purpose to my understanding exists `SAML qttribute query`
And this is where I need help. I'm attempting to use `pysaml2` or `python3-saml` both do not support attribute query.

I'm attempting to build the query attribute manually failed so far but will work in the end.

The real question is: am I on the right path?

Are attribute queries the right way to go - since looking at other products and samples around the web I do NOT see that attribute query gets used that much

The alternative I see right now is to use SAML for authentication - and combine it with LDAP for authorization - I've seen this solution done in a few other products.